# Easy number theory/proof by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

This is my attempt to solve the following question: "Use induction to show that if $(a,b)=1$ (greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$), then $(a,b^n)=1$ for all $n\geq 1$."

We have that $(a,b)=1$, which implies that $1=au + bv$ for some integers $u,v$. For the induction, assume that $(a,b^k)=1$, which implies $1=ar + b^{k}s$ for some integers $r,s$. Multiplying these equations together yields $1=(au + bv)(ar + b^{k}s)$. We then get

$$1=a^{2}ur + aub^{k}s + bvar + b^{k+1}vs$$ which simplifies to
$$1=a(aur + ub^{k}s + bvr) + b^{k+1}vs$$.

$(a,b^{k+1})$ divides the right side of the equation, which implies that $(a,b^{k+1})$ also divides the left side of the equation, and since $(x,y)$ of any integers $x$ and $y$ is at least $1$, it follows that $(a,b^{k+1})=1$. This completes the proof by induction, since we have assumed our base case of $n=1$.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback if any of the steps in the solution are wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solution is perfectly fine.

Comment: Clearer: the same Bezout-based proof show $\ (a,b)=1=(a,c)\,\Rightarrow\, (a,bc) = 1,\,$ so by induction if $a$ is coprime to all $\,b_i\,$ then it is coprime to their product. OP is the special case $b_i = b\ \ $

Comment: If you know modular arithmetic then it boils down to the fact that if If $b_i$ are invertible $\bmod a$ then so is their product - which is also an obvious inductive proof using $(bc)^{-1}\equiv c^{-1} b^{-1}.\,$

Comment: just started learning the basics of it, but thanks for the tip! Maybe I can revisit it when I am more used to modular arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

This solution is correct, very clear, and easy to follow. Well done!

The only downside is that this question is very easily generalisable and your proof method is very specific.